# how to goto specific page number including title with permalink

Tags: php, permalinks

Several pages are subs of main page account. Example: account\service.

How to goto specific page number including page title with permalink?

I have tried this:

```
$GLOBALS['create_page_service'] = '1281';
$out .= '<a href="'.get_page_link($GLOBALS['create_page_finder']).'">'.get_the_title($GLOBALS['create_page_finder']).'</a>';
```

Result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong index:

```
$GLOBALS['create_page_service'] = '1281';
# Your code uses 'create_page_finder' below
$out .= '<a href="'.get_page_link($GLOBALS['create_page_finder']).'">'.get_the_title($GLOBALS['create_page_finder']).'</a>';

$GLOBALS['create_page_service'] = '1281';
# my changed code uses 'create_page_service' below
$out .= '<a href="'.get_page_link($GLOBALS['create_page_service']).'">'.get_the_title($GLOBALS['create_page_service']).'</a>';
```

As an aside, I would avoid using globals whenever you can.

Comment: Result of your code is page: account
Why? I am on account and want with this <a href> that visitor can go to the service page with that link.
When I use get_page_link() I never get the subpage = 1281.
That is what I do not understand and like to fix.

Comment: If the Page with ID 1281 is indeed the service page, then it should work. Question: is the Service page an action "Page" in the WordPress sense or a "Post?"

Comment: You're right. I did not copied correct the page ID. It was 12819!
Now I get the correct page. Thanks for your reply.